# If an object exists in JSON then print another value, if not, print nothing

Tags: python, json

```
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"}

url = f'https:............'
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
events = response['events']
for event in events:
    List_of_Urls = []
    List_of_Urls.append(event['id'])

    slug = event['slug']

    for List_of_Url in List_of_Urls:
        try:
            url2 = f'https://.............../{List_of_Url}/.........'
            response2 = requests.get(url2, headers=headers).json()
            
            if response2['graphPoints']:
                print(slug)
        except:
            pass
```

Response JSON example 1:

```
{
  "graphPoints": [
    {
      "minute": 1,
      "value": -2
    }
```

Response JSON example 2:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Not Found"
  }
}
```

My idea is that if there is `graphPoints` in `JSON`, then printing the `slug` value, but in the direct `if response2['graphPoints']:` value for `true or false` doesn't work, how should I make it work?

Comment: Why don't you just check for response code and ignore non 200?

Comment: besides the @chasmani's answer, there is also an option to exploit short-circuitry and just `print(response2.get('graphPoints') and slug)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its a JSON object I think you can just do:

```
if 'graphPoints' in response2:
    print(slug)
```

Comment: Hello friend @chasmani , thanks for the support. I added two links inside a question to demonstrate the answers JSON gives. I tried the two ways you indicated but I was not successful!

Comment: the second one is an antipattern. `key in some_dict`  is the intended way of checking dict membership

Comment: @BrondbyIF please post more information on how it doesn't work. The first snippet is actually the one you're looking for

Comment: Hi @Marat Actually I don't know why it's not working, the code runs and doesn't print any value, but when I use ```if (response2['graphPoints'][0]['minute'] >= 1):```, then it returns the prints, so I work around the problem but I wanted something exact on top of the graphPoints existence

Comment: @BrondbyIF the answer contains a typo, `graphpoints` instead of `graphPoints`

Comment: That's correct mate @Marat, haha! A big little problem that I hadn't seen, thank you very much for the alert!